# Extracting cell values from a QTableWidget and assigning them to independent variables, whilst iterating row by row

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtablewidget

beginner here working with PyQt5 in Python and struggling to find the exact answer to the question I have.

Not sure my title does it justice, but am not sure exactly how to put it into words.

Context:

I have a QTableWidget in my PyQt5 GUI, and what I want to do is row by row, assign specific cell values to my variables.

Example Table and section of code:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY6IT.png)

```
#Table for inputing experiment conditions
    self.table1 = QTableWidget(self)
    column_labels = ['Pump 1: Flow Rate (uL/min)', 'Pump 2: Flow Rate (ul/min)', 'Collection Volume (uL)']
    self.table1.setColumnCount(3)
    self.table1.setRowCount(1)
    self.table1.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(column_labels)
```

The table also has the ability to insert more rows with a click of a button.

My program will ultimately take the value (row, column) - (0,0), (0,1) and (0,2) as separate values and assign them each to seperate variables

flow_rate1 = (0,0)

flow_rate2 = (0,1)

col_volume = (0,2)

Each time a new variable is created, this data will be fed downstream to more code which will do something else in my program (I know how to do this bit).

After that run has completed, I want it to be able to go down to the next row and change the variables to correspond to the next row, then repeat the code.

flow_rate1 = (1,0)

flow_rate2 = (1,1)

col_volume = (1,2)

and so on..

So I figure this will be some kind of for loop which starts in the following manner

```
    flow_rate1 = 0
    flow_rate2 = 0
    col_volume = 0

    runs = self.table1.rowcount() 
    
    for i in range(runs):
        **Code indicating variable row:**
            flow_rate1 = **code here assigning variable position**
            flow_rate2 = **code here assigning variable position**
            col_volume = **code here assigning variable position**
            **More code doing something with the data here**
```

I am not sure where to start with:

1. Giving my variable the specific cell value.
2. Repeating the code row by row, for n rows after my code has finished executing.

Any tips, example code or resources where to start looking would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to get the values of each cell? Then just get the item with `table.item(row, column)` and read its `text()` or `data(Qt.DisplayRole)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @musicamante for the help, that was really helpful, it kind of helped me see it differently (i.e I was not thinking about it logically). Solution was simpler than I was making it sound...

Here is my answer: If anyone has a simpler way, let me know.

runs = self.table1.rowCount()

```
    row = 0
    
    for i in range(runs):
        
        p1_fr = self.table1.item(row, 0).text()
        
        p2_fr = self.table1.item(row, 1).text()
        
        col_vol = float(self.table1.item(row,2).text())
        
        **Other code here executing my program**
        
        row += 1
```

Comment: Setting `row` and incrementing is unnecessary, since you're using the row count. Just do `for row in range(self.table1.rowCount()):`